# Reference data from a array to another array in C

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I want to reference new array to address from another array in C code like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int b[6];
    unsigned long long int *c = &a[5];
    unsigned long long int *d = &b[5];
    int size = 6;
    for(;size>0;size--,c--,d--){
        *d = *c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but my code didn't work. can you tell me whats wrong in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type of your pointer doesn’t match the data type of the array

Comment: And it's causing accessing outside the array bounds because the pointer data size is bigger than the array element size.

Comment: you means I change *c & *d data type to int?

Comment: Yes. That will fix your issue.

Comment: This and fixing what @Barmar said.

Answer (score 2):

These declarations

```
unsigned long long int *c = &a[5];
unsigned long long int *d = &b[5];
```

are incorrect because the declared objects have the type `unsigned long long int *` but are initialized by expressions of the type `int *`. Thus dereferencing the declared pointers you can get unexpected results.

If you want to use the pointer arithmetic in a for loop for example to copy the first array into the second array in the reverse order then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { N = 6 };
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int b[N];
    
    for ( int * c = a + N, *d = b; c != a; )
    {
        *d++ = *--c;
    }
    
    for ( const int *d = b; d != b + N; ++d )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *d );
    }
    
    putchar ( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```